# Get a value of key from JSON response in Python

Tags: python, json, request

I am accessing an API through a get request from which I get a response.

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
symbol = "AAPL"
end_point="https://api.polygon.io/v2/snapshot/locale/us/markets/stocks/tickers/"+symbol+"?apiKey=my_key"

r=requests.get(end_point).json()


print(r)
print(r['min'])
```

`print(r)` returned:

```
{'request_id': '2735c0be51de7719fd99460fe8696080', 'status': 'OK', 'ticker': {'day': {'c': 172.93, 'h': 175.48, 'l': 172.37, 'o': 174.14, 'v': 65575561, 'vw': 174.0984}, 'lastQuote': {'P': 172.83, 'S': 3, 'p': 172.82, 's': 1, 't': 1644524332922450142}, 'lastTrade': {'c': None, 'i': '139592', 'p': 172.8199, 's': 2014, 't': 1644524331573573011, 'x': 4}, 'min': {'av': 65559987, 'c': 172.9, 'h': 173.14, 'l': 172.89, 'o': 173.09, 'v': 107429, 'vw': 173.0138}, 'prevDay': {'c': 176.28, 'h': 176.65, 'l': 174.9, 'o': 176.05, 'v': 71204538, 'vw': 175.8287}, 'ticker': 'AAPL', 'todaysChange': -3.46, 'todaysChangePerc': -1.963, 'updated': 1644524331573573011}}
```

but when I try to access the key "min", I get key error:

```
KeyError: 'min'
```

This is super-simple. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `r['ticker']['min']`

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question, but I wonder if it can be closed under the "Typo" official reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
r['ticker']['min']
```

Comment: bingo! now i understand how it works and what I did wrong!

Answer (score 0):

the key `min` is inside `ticker`. Do this:

```
r['ticker']['min']
```